# best way to generate btc wallet with mnemonic phrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

Im fairly new to crypto but after some further exposure it seems like it should be possible to do what im trying to do

I want to gift a small amount of btc to my nieces and nephews. My idea was to laminate a small card with their wallet id and a mnemonic phrase; then transfer some btc to this wallet from my own accounts

then when they are all grown up they can withdraw these funds

what is the best way (or software) to create multiple btc accounts using mnemonic phrases?

Comment: What do you mean by wallet id, do you mean bitcoin address? Also when you say you want to create multiple btc _accounts_ using mnemonic is confusing, accounts has a specific meaning within an HD key chain, but I don't think that is what you are asking. I think you are asking how to create multiple mnemonics and get their first corresponding address within the keychain, is that right?

Comment: i think thats right.  i want to generate something with a mnemonic phrase that i can then send some btc to and eventually can be withdrawn from using the mnemonic phrase

Comment: It sounds like you just want multiple wallets. With a wallet like Electrum (for example) you can simply create a new wallet for each niece/nephew and write down each mnemonic phrase. https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-create-a-new-electrum-wallet-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click 'Generate' on [this page](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) (although I highly don't recommend using the online version, see below for more) to generate mnemonic phrases and use them. The site supports several languages, multiple currencies not just Bitcoin & more.

The site is also open source and I highly recommend using this offline than the online one for obvious security reasons: https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39

Comment: Downvote: it is very bad advice to generate wallets in an online environment as you've suggested. Instead, emphasis should be put on the second part of your answer: if you're going to use the Ian Coleman tool, you should download the source code and run it on a computer that does not ever connect to the internet.

Comment: @chytrik And that’s exactly what I suggested! You’re welcome to edit my answer to emphasise the second half if you like

Comment: People are prone to just reading only as far as they need to, in this case that could be just your first sentence, and generating wallets in an online web-page is probably the least secure method you could recommend. I don't mean to be rude in my comment, but I think it is imperative to recommend best practices whenever possible. To do otherwise presents a very real risks to users of this site.

Comment: @chytrik 100% agree!

Comment: @chytrik I've edited it now, what do you think?

Comment: I think the disclaimer is a good addition, I changed my vote. Cheers

Comment: after i generate my phrases with this tool (offline).  how i do i create the wallet with them?  i dont see a create wallet button, seems like i have to send some command to the btc chain to have my wallet actually created.

Comment: @owengerig No command is required! As soon as you have generated a wallet, it exists.  As soon as you have sent BTC to it, it exists on the blockchain. So to answer your question, after you have generated your phrases, you've created a wallet that's ready to use.

Comment: do i send btc to the BIP39 Seed or BIP32 Root Key?  there is also "Account Extended Public Key"

Comment: @owengerig The address you should send too should be listed as “BTC address”

Comment: theres a list of "Derived Addresses" is that what your referring to?

Comment: If it says “BTC address and it’s in an btc address format then yea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117189/discussion-between-owen-gerig-and-lemon).